# Opening Files in C

Tags: c, data-files

### Full Edit:

I am getting frustrated, I don't know what am I doing wrong in here 
I still have so many stuff to do in the code but I can't even open a file to continue my work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
char letter;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("‪‪‪C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\data.txt","r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("error");
    getch();
    exit(1);
}

while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&letter)!=EOF)
putchar(letter);
getch();
fclose(fp);
}‪
```

Picture of the path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LulWJ.jpg

Still prints error

Comment: `while(EOF!=fscanf(input, "%c", &letter)) putchar(letter);`

Comment: We are not a tutoring service. Do you have a specific question not answered in your C book?

Comment: I was just asking a question (I know what EOF does but i didn't know how to use it till now)  I didn't ask for a full program code

Comment: @Bolar your new code is wrong, please read the comments more carefully. `while(!EOF)` is always false. The important point is to **always check the return value from `scanf` function family**. I suggest reading the man page for a function that is causing you problems.

Comment: "I know what EOF does" hmm, `EOF` does not ***do*** anything, it is a defined value returned from some functions, usually `-1` to signify "End-Of-File".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, firstly let's take a look at your file path. There are two ways to acces a file from your local storage:

**relative addresses** if the file has the same root folder as your application

**absolute addresses** if the file is in a determined place on your machine's storage

I see that you are trying to use an absolute address to read from your file. Your path is correct but you have to take care about string formatting in C because the \ character could be interpreted as something else.

I would suggest to use this instead ( double back-slash )

```
input=fopen("‪C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\data.txt","r");
```

This will prevent string formatting interpretations.

Secondly, EOF is just a predefined macro constant and i think it is equal to -1 so your while(! (-1) ) code is not a good ideea for reading until the end of the file.

In order to read from a file until you reach the its end i would consider this property of fscanf() :
***fscanf() returns EOF when it reaches the end of the file.***

```
while(fscanf(input,"%ch",&letter) != EOF) {
putchar(letter);
}
```

This way of reading from a file should do the job.

Comment: Corrected those lines and it still prints "File not found"
Seriously this is annoying....

Comment: Make sure your file have the same path or extension

Answer (score 0):

**To read everything from a text file and store its contents into a buffer:**

First, you should count how many characters there are in the text file:

```
size_t get_file_len(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t num = 0;

    while (fgetc(fp) != EOF)
        num++;

    return (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET) == 0 ? num : 0);
}
```

Then allocate memory for a buffer large enough and read all the characters:

```
char *load_text(const char *path)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    size_t num = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    int c = 0;

   /* open the file in text mode */
   fp = fopen(path, "r");
   if (!fp)
       return NULL;

   /* if the file was empty or if an error occurred, return error */
   if ((num = get_file_len(fp)) == 0) {
       fclose(fp);

       return NULL;
   }

   buf = malloc(num + 1);
   if (!buf) {
       fclose(fp);

       return NULL;
   }

   while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
       buf[i++] = (char)c;

   /* ensure that the string is null-terminated */
   buf[i] = '\0';

   fclose(fp);

   return buf;
}
```

Also, in C, all escape sequences begin with a '\' (backslash), so if you wanted to write a backslash in a string or a char you should write it as a '\\' (double backslash):

```
input=fopen("‪C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\data.txt","r");
```

Answer (score -2):

pretty simple here :

```
    while(!feof(input)){
    fscanf(input,"%c",&letter);
    putchar(letter);
    }
```

and remember to close file using fclose(input);

Comment: [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @pmg I've written `while(!feof(input))` works ! You can verify with **Programming in C - Gottfried**.